# Pandas Concat Adding Null Cells/Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes which look like this. Headers are indicative - the dataframes don't actually have any headers (titles).

```
**Dataframe 1**
Browser_name          Count
IE                      4
Chrome                  7
Firefox                 6
DDG                     2

**Dataframe 2**
Browser_name          Count
IE                      6
Chrome                  18
Firefox                 9
DDG                     4
```

The output I want is a dataframe with browser name in first column and sum of their counts in second columns as shown below.

```
**Final_Dataframe**
Browser_name          Count
IE                      10
Chrome                  25
Firefox                 15
DDG                     6
```

I tried using concat of the two dataframes and then planned to use pivot but I am stuck at concat itself. It adds empty columns for each row so not able to proceed to next steps.

All help appreciated.

Comment: there is same number of rows and same order of first column values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is 2 columns DataFrame solution is create index by first column and create `Series` by seelcting by position and then use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html), last [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
s1 = df1.set_index(df1.columns[0]).iloc[:, 0]
s2 = df2.set_index(df2.columns[0]).iloc[:, 0]

df = s1.add(s2).reset_index()
df.columns = ['Browser_name','Count']
```

Or set columns names first:

```
df1.columns = ['Browser_name','Count']
df2.columns = ['Browser_name','Count']
s1 = df1.set_index('Browser_name')['Count']
s2 = df2.set_index('Browser_name')['Count']

df = s1.add(s2).reset_index()

print (df)
  Browser_name  Count
0           IE     10
1       Chrome     25
2      Firefox     15
3          DDG      6
```

If input are `Series`:

```
print (type(df1))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print (type(df2))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

df = df1.add(df2).reset_index()
df.columns = ['Browser_name','Count']
print (df)
  Browser_name  Count
0           IE     10
1       Chrome     25
2      Firefox     15
3          DDG      6
```

Answer (score 1):

just add two data frame

```
df1['total'] = df1.iloc[:,1]+df2.iloc[:,1]
df3 = df1.iloc[:,[0,2]]
df3.columns = ['Browser_name','Count']
df3.columns = ['Browser_name','Count']
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case we can use inbuilt method **add** .

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'Browser_name':"IE","Count":4},{'Browser_name':"Chrome","Count":7},{"Browser_name":"Firefox","Count":6}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'Browser_name':"IE","Count":6},{'Browser_name':"Chrome","Count":18},{"Browser_name":"Firefox","Count":15}])

sumData = df1["Count"].add(df2["Count"],fill_value=0)
sumData = pd.DataFrame({'Browser_name':df2["Browser_name"], 'Count':sumData.values})
print(sumData)

=========
  Browser_name  Count
0           IE     10
1       Chrome     25
2      Firefox     21
```